# No notification on a deleted and restored answer

Tags: feature-request, deleted-answers, notifications

[This answer](//judaism.stackexchange.com/posts/62562/revisions) to my question was deleted by its author about a half hour after posting. He edited it some and undeleted it. I come back to the site and do not find any notification of a new answer to my question. I assume what happened is this: The answer generated a notification, but its deletion deleted that notification and its undeletion did not generate a new one. So I didn't know I had a new answer to my question until someone happened to alert me to it.

(Note: it *was* in my [notifications list](//judaism.stackexchange.com/users/current?tab=responses&sort=answers#user-tab-responses) (until it was just re-deleted), but not in the top-of-page inbox-notifier.)

This seems like a bug; or, at least, something that should IMO, as a new feature, be changed.